# Unable to add SOAP service reference to ASP.Net Core Web API project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, soap-client

I have created a ASP.Net Core Web API project from which I want to call a SOAP web service and get data. I am struck at adding the wsdl reference to the project. I am trying to add the service using "Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider".
It is always failing with  Access denied error as below:

```
Importing web service metadata ...
Number of service endpoints found: 2
Scaffolding service reference code ...
Error:System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (5): Access is denied.
Error:   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
Error:   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
Error:   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, TimeSpan startupTime, ITelemetry telemetryClient)
Error:   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Run.RunCommand.Run(String[] args)
Error:   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.Command.Execute(Action`1 processStarted)
Error:   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Run.RunCommand.Execute()
Error:   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
Error:   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.Command.Execute()
Done.
```

Whatever I try, I am hitting the same error.

I added the same web service to a .Net client library and it is adding there without any issues. Request for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Due to some access issue it was not allowing me to insert. I created a temporary ASP.Net core project and copied over the the reference files.